Querying canceled job
received an email via Alert Manager telling me a job was canceled due to a script syntax error.
Not sure which email it is but when I query the Job data view for that JobID, I get 0 results. At first I thought it was because it was canceled, but the JobStatus should include canceled jobs as far as I can tell. Here's my basic query in SQL Studio.
SELECT JobID, JobStatus, EmailName FROM _Job WHERE JobID = '#########'

are you doing this in the BU the job belongs to? Even at the EID level _job is only jobs from that MID

@EazyE, I believe so; the MID on the email aligns with the MID when I hover over the BU name.
